# iOS: UICollectionView content reset and dequeueReusableCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Okay the situation goes as follows:

I have a collection view where in `cellForRow` I am using `dequeueReusableCell` to reuse the cells. On each cell I have a custom `UIView` object that is added as a subview.

Now, under a certain circumstance I must re-layout the collection view entirely. When this happens

- Clear all item from data model
- Call `deleteItems` for all visible cells' index paths
- Call `reloadData`

At this point the collection view is empty and there are no cells displayed.

Now if I update my model again with data and reload the collection view - In `cellForRow` `dequeueReusableCell` returns reused cells/the added UIView as explained above is there!/- it does not initialize new cell objects even though the collection view was empty before the current update. I am not sure if this is the expected behaviour or I have some other problem in my code, however my question is - how can get to a point where I `reset` all the content on the collection view and `dequeueReusableCell` returns a newly initialized cell object.

Comment: Why do you need a newly initialized cell object? You can do any resetting you need in `prepareForReuse`.

Comment: The behaviour is correct. Clearing your data model does nothing to the cell pool. Your code in your cell and `cellForItemAt` should be stateless; it should always do what is required to configure the cell based on the model regardless of whether it is a new cell or a reused cell.

Comment: In `cellForRow` after getting a cell object from `dequeueReusableCell` I am initializing a new UIView instance and adding it as a subview to my celll. In order to avoid initializing this view every time I am checking whether the view already exists and skip initializing a new one if so. However, as explained in the question I need to have a mechanism to reset everything. This is a special event and only then I want to be able to recreate each cell and its corresponding `UIView` instance, after that cell reuse will continue as normal - do not create this view on every `cellForRow` call

Answer (score 0):

I have learnt this the hard way! Save yourself some time Petar by knowing this that In any collection view/tableview, anytime there is any change of constraint or any UI element in its layout structure, you should ALWAYS, and ALWAYS make another prototype cell. It is the ONLY correct way, so don't think you ll be putting some more time in making another cell.

As I read your comment where you said you ll initiliaze another view based on that one condition where you want to reset everything. Just have another cell prototype with that another view and dequeue that now.

Hope it solves your problem

Comment: I don't think this is correct. You shouldn't be initializing a new cell each time - this is why `dequeueReusableCell` is there for.

Comment: No u ve wrongly understood me. I am not asking to initialize a new cell everytime. I am only saying, have another prototype cell for the new kind of UI of the cell, and then dequeue that one based on your condition.

Comment: @Petar Let me know if there is still any confusion.